# Understanding GAS Trigger Total Runtime Quota

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, quota

I remember reading that Total Triggers Runtime is 1 hour for Consumer type users. I don't think I really understand what that means.

Let's say I programmatically create a trigger to run every 10 minutes, like so ...

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(10)
  .create();
```

... and let it run around the clock.

myFunction does something very not time consuming like appending a couple rows to a spreadsheet.

My question is, when am I going to hit the said '1 hour' limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see under [Apps Script quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

[image]
[image]

### Those times refer to the total execution time of the function(s) that is / are being run on trigger.

When you go on https://script.google.com/u/0/home/executions, you can see all your executions, you can also see the executions for a particular trigger.

It should look like this:
[image]

So, if you sum the durations of all the executions of all the functions of type `Trigger` within the last 24 hours - it cannot exceed the `Triggers total runtime`.

Comment: @TheMaster: You mean I should format the link in my answer as a link instead as a code block?